# How to access the slug value in my url?

Tags: php, url, slug

I'd like to know why my code does not show any results.

I have a link in the `home.php` page, like this:

```
<a href="../musica/'.$row['slug'].'">Click here</a>`
```

and in the `musica.php` page, I access the slug with:

```
$slug = $_GET['slug'];
```

and my query looks like this:

```
select * from musical layers where slug = $slug
```

but it is not returning anything.

This is the full url that my hyperlink goes to:

```
scrashmusicas.epizy.com/musica/wesley-safadao-banda-garota-safada
```

There are no errors, but I am not able to get the slug value. Can anyone help me?

This is the relevant portion of my musica.php file:

```
$slug = $_GET['slug'];
$result_capa = "select * from capas_musicas where slug = $slug";
$resultados_capa = mysqli_query($conn, $result_capa);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultados_capa)){
    echo '
        <li>
            <a href="../musica/'.$row['slug'].'">
                <div class="box_destaque">
                    <img src="'.$row['capa_album'].'" border="0"/>
                    <strong>'.$row['nome_album'].'</strong>
                    <span>'.$row['categoria_album'].'</span>
                </div>
            </a>
        </li>
    ';
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There are a few things to address...

```
$slug = $_GET['slug'];
```

If/When there is no `slug` key in the `$_GET` superglobal, you are going to receive Notices.  You need to check if it `isset()` before trying to access/use the value.

```
$result_capa = "select * from capas_musicas where slug = $slug";
```

This query is insecure.  You need to use prepared statements with placeholders EVERY TIME you use user-supplied or generally insecure data in a query.  For your current code, `$slug` needs to be single-quote-wrapped at a minimum (unless of course it is an integer -- but still, use a prepared statement)

As for `$_GET`, you are not offering a querystring in your `href` value, so nothing is delivered via `$_GET`.

Calling `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` on your `musica.php` script will yield this string value:

```
/musica/wesley-safadao-banda-garota-safada
```

To access the slug value, use this:

```
$path=parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],PHP_URL_PATH);
$slug=substr($path,strrpos($path,'/')+1);
```

or just:

```
$slug=substr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],8);  // access substring after "/musica/"
```

Comment: @Bruno Do you have the correct path?  Do you need to go up one dirctory?  I mean, is `../` correct for your case?  Notice that I am advising you to use `musica.php` rather than `musica/` before the querystring.

Comment: my goal is to make a friendly url, if I use `music.php` it will work, but it will not be friendly, I've looked for a lot of articles about it and I can not get an answer

Comment: I'll improve my answer. I know what you want now.  One moment

Comment: What do you see when you `echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];` on `musica.php` ?  I just need to know if you need to further prepare that value.

Comment: @Bruno okay, I've edit my answer.  You should be right to implement my suggested `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` method

Answer (score 0):

Try changing to this:

```
<a href="../musica/?slug='.$row['slug'].'">Click here</a>
```

Comment: it did not work, and even if this method works it would not be what I need, understand?

Comment: Please show your full code or at least the full functions in the two files

Comment: https://pastebin.com/Um4jdXpP < `home.php` https://pastebin.com/31qvM8f0 < `musica.php`

Comment: Ok. try this one `<a href="../musica/'.$row['slug'].'?slug='.$row['slug'].'">Click here</a>`
Then in your query, put single quotes around $slug => `'$slug'`